# operation timedout while publishing artifacts to gitlab using goreleser

Tags: go, gitlab, goreleaser

I am using golang to create a simple CLI application. I am using GoReleaser to release this to Gitlab. I followed the steps outlined in https://goreleaser.com/quick-start/ to release changes to gitlab.
I have generated a personal access token with API scope. I am tagging the changes and pushing them before I use the goreleaser to publish artifacts.

I always get the error which says release failed after 452.34s error=github/gitlab/gitea releases: failed to publish artifacts: Get "https://PRIVATEGITLABURL/api/v4/projects/PRIVATE_GITLAB_PROJECT/releases/v1%2E0%2E3": dial tcp IP_ADDRESS:443: connect: operation timed out.

My .gorelease.yml file

```
before:
  hooks:
    # You may remove this if you don't use go modules.
    - go mod tidy
    # you may remove this if you don't need go generate
    - go generate ./...
builds:
  - env:
      - CGO_ENABLED=0
    goos:
      - windows
snapshot:
  name_template: "{{ incpatch .Version }}-next"
changelog:
  sort: asc
  filters:
    exclude:
      - '^docs:'
      - '^test:'
# .goreleaser.yml
gitlab_urls:
  api: https://PRIVATE_GITLAB_REPO/api/v4/
  download: https://PRIVATE_GITLAB_REPO
  # set to true if you use a self-signed certificate
  skip_tls_verify: false
```

Any Ideas? My gitlab version is GitLab Enterprise Edition 14.1.5-ee

Answer (score 2):

Check first if this is because of [`goreleaser/goreleaser` issue 1879](https://github.com/goreleaser/goreleaser/issues/1879) ("
Using goreleaser behind a http(s) proxy "), which is supported since [PR 1885](https://github.com/goreleaser/goreleaser/pull/1885) and goreleaser v0.147.0:

- either your GitLab server is accessible through internet, and you have not set `HTTP(S)_PROXY` environment variables
- or your GitLab server is on your intranet, you have set `HTTP(S)_PROXY`, but forgot the `NO_PROXY` (to *not* use the proxy when accessing through `https://` an intranet resource).

---

[Batuhan Apaydın](https://github.com/developer-guy) suggests in the [OP's discussion](https://github.com/goreleaser/goreleaser/discussions/2517#discussioncomment-1388645) to apply the [gitlab configuration](https://goreleaser.com/customization/release/#gitlab):

```yaml
# .goreleaser.yml
release:
  # Default is extracted from the origin remote URL or empty if its private hosted.
  # You can also use Gitlab's internal project id by setting it in the name
  #  field and leaving the owner field empty.
  gitlab:
    owner: user
    name: repo.
```

---

The [OP GrailsTest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4690425/grailstest) confirms, from GH discussion, in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69340444/operation-timedout-while-publishing-artifacts-to-gitlab-using-goreleser#comment122583583_69341890):

> I could not push my release as I can only access GitLab via SSH.
> HTTP does not seem to work. Https has never worked on my machine, possibly because I have not set environment variables.
>
> I could get this working on my colleagues machine who can access GitLab via HHTPS and SSH.

Comment: If not, I will monitor your discussion at https://github.com/goreleaser/goreleaser/discussions/2517

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I could not push my release as I can only access gitlab via ssh. HTTP does not seem to work . Https has never worked on my machine, possibly because I have not set environment variables. I could get this working on my colleagues machine who can access gitlab via https and ssh. Thank you so much :)

Comment: @GrailsTest OK. I have updated the answer accordingly.